# Creates a new excel file while inserting other time in excel file in c# windows form.

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this below function which inserts value to particualr cell in excel file. When i call this function second time it opens a new excel file and both time the value is entered into differnt excel file. How to have open single excel file and both of my value are entered into same excel file.

```
   private bool insertIntoExcel(string pathname , string sheetname ,int excelRow, int excelColumn,string value) 
            {
                try
                {

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                    oXL.Visible = true;

                    oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook mWorkBook = oXL.Workbooks.Open(pathname, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", true, false, 0, true, false, false);

                    //Get all the sheets in the workbook

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets mWorkSheets = mWorkBook.Worksheets;

                    //Get the allready exists sheet

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet mWSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)mWorkSheets.get_Item(sheetname);

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = mWSheet1.UsedRange;


                    mWSheet1.Cells[excelRow, excelColumn] = value;                      

                }catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;

            }
```

Comment: try closing excel instance explicitly. I suggest Adding `mWorkBook .Close(1); oXL.Quit();` statements in `finally` block.

Answer (score 0):

Do not new a Excel Application and open a workbook every time. You should keep the workbook as a handler and keep it. Use the handler to do insertion or other operations.